# Change orientation of a div

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
  <p>abcd efgh ijkl mno</p>
</div>

div{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  font-size:40px;
}
```

Now if the content's height is greater than the `div` height, content comes out of the div vertically. Div fixes the width to 400px and the content will not come out of the div horizontally. I want my content to come out of div horizontally. sorry for my bad english.

thanks in advance.

see the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/ME3Pd/10/) where content respects width of the div.. not the height.

I want the other way where content respects the height.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to restrict the width whilst NOT restricting the width.

Comment: yes seems like creepy but that is the situation with me.... :( wat ever the content might be, it should fit in the height, leaving no white space. @Moob

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible in CSS. Are you open to a JS solution such as http://jsfiddle.net/zuaG6/

Comment: thanks @Moob nice solution. I sholud enquire if i can use this js solution :)

Comment: Be my guest. I've posted it as a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're open to a JS solution you could resize the content, making it wider until it fits within the vertical bounds:

```
var bounds = document.getElementById("bounds");
var content = document.getElementById("content");
while(content.offsetHeight>bounds.offsetHeight){
    content.style.width = (content.offsetWidth+1)+'px';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zuaG6/

Comment: But what is this fiddle for!!?

Comment: @GreenWizard - sorry, don't know how that got there. I've corrected the link. Thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you really want is `min-width`

```
div{
  min-width:400px;
  height:200px;
  font-size:40px;
}
```